# Algorithm to find all the exact divisors of a given integer

Tags: c, algorithm, numbers, performance, factors

I want to find all the exact divisors of a number.
Currently I have this:

```
{
   int n;
   int i=2;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   while(i<=n/2)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
                  printf("%d,",i);
        i++;
     }
   getch();
}
```

Is there any way to improve it?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

First, your code should have the condition of `i <= n/2`, otherwise it can miss one of the factors, for example 6 will not be printed if n=12.

Run the loop to the square root of the number (ie. `i <= sqrt(n)`) and print both `i` and `n/i` (both will be multiples of n).

```
{
   int n;
   int i=2;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   while(i <= sqrt(n))
    {
        if(n%i==0) {
            printf("%d,",i);
            if (i != (n / i)) {
                printf("%d,",n/i);
            }
        } 

        i++;
    }
   getch();
}
```

Note :

- For a perfect square, so that the square root is not printed twice, the additional checking is done at the end of loop for `i*i == n` as suggested by @chepner.
- If you want all the factors in ascending order store the values in an array then at the end of the loop sort all the numbers and display.

Comment: you can change `printf("%d,", i);printf("%d,", n/i);` to `printf("%d,", i); if(i != n/i){printf("%d,", n/i);}`.For a perfect square, it will not print twice of the root.

Comment: You can avoid the multiple checks for `n/i !=i` by iterating over `i < sqrt(n)`, which implies that `n/i != i`, then checking `i=sqrt(n)` outside the while loop as a single edge case.

Comment: Great thought , my bad not to realise it. Will add it, thanks.

Comment: what is the proof that all the divisors could be found by looping sqrt(n) times only ? please explain.

Comment: How ? It will print 2 and 4. Are you referring to the fact that 1 and 8 will not be printed ?

Comment: @LoveToCode take i=1 instead of i=2

Comment: @Rndm - note that `i <= sqrt(n)` promotes i to a double. You could use `i <= (int)sqrt(n)` to avoid this. It would be faster to change `if (i != (n / i))` to `if (i*i != n)` .

Answer (score 4):

Finding all divisors by using "finding all prime factors" in C (faster)
and up to 18 digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned int FindDivisors(unsigned long long divisors[], unsigned long long N) {
    unsigned int lastdiv = 0;
    divisors[lastdiv++] = 1;
    unsigned long long powerfactor = 1;
    unsigned long long number = N;
    while ((number & 1) == 0) {
        powerfactor <<= 1;
        divisors[lastdiv++] = powerfactor;
        number >>= 1;
    }

    unsigned long long factor = 3; unsigned long long upto = lastdiv;
    powerfactor = 1;
    while (factor * factor <= number) {
        if (number % factor == 0) {
            powerfactor *= factor;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < upto; i++)
                divisors[lastdiv++] = divisors[i] * powerfactor;
            number /= factor;
        }
        else {
            factor += 2; upto = lastdiv;
            powerfactor = 1;
        }
    }

    if (number > 1) {
        if (number != factor) {
            upto = lastdiv;
            powerfactor = 1;
        }
        powerfactor *= number;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < upto; i++)
            divisors[lastdiv++] = divisors[i] * powerfactor;
    }
    return lastdiv;
}

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    if( *(long long*)a-*(long long*)b < 0 ) return -1;
    if( *(long long*)a-*(long long*)b > 0 ) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned long long N = 2;
    unsigned int Ndigit = 1;
    if (argc > 1) {
        N = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        Ndigit = strlen(argv[1]);
    }
    unsigned int maxdiv[] = {1, 4, 12, 32, 64, 128, 240, 448, 768, 1344,
                             2304, 4032, 6720, 10752, 17280, 26880, 41472, 64512, 103680};

    unsigned long long divisors[maxdiv[Ndigit]];
    unsigned int size = FindDivisors(divisors, N);
    printf("Number of divisors = %u\n", size);

    qsort(divisors, size, sizeof(unsigned long long), cmp);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%llu ", divisors[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple linear search can be improved by first throwing out all factors of 2. That can be done by simple bit shifting, or count training zero's with a nice intrinsic function. That's very fast in either case. Then run the algorithm suggested by shg (which will run much faster now that the powers of two aren't present), and combine the result with all the possible powers of two (don't forget this step). It helps a lot for inputs that have a lot of training zero's, but it even helps if they don't - you wouldn't have to test any even divisors anymore, so the loop becomes half as long.

Throwing out some constant low factors (but bigger than 2) can also help. Modulo with a constant is almost certainly optimized by the compiler (or if not, you can do it yourself), but more importantly, that means there are fewer divisors left to test. Don't forget to combine that factor with the divisors you find.

You can also factorize the number completely (use your favourite algorithm - probably Pollard's Rho would be best), and then print all products (except the empty product and the full product) of the factors. This has a good chance of ending up being faster for bigger inputs - Pollard's Rho algorithm finds factors very quickly compared to a simple linear search, there are usually less factors than proper divisors, and the last step (enumerating the products) only involves fast math (no divisions). This mostly helps for numbers with very small factors, which Rho finds the quickest.

Comment: could u give an example of how to remove all the factors of 2 by bit shifting.Bit operations are faster so that would surely improve the performance.

Comment: @jairaj say you take 24, the square root is almost 5 but not quite, so you'd have to test the divisors 2, 3 and 4 (they would generate 12, 8 and 6, respectively). If you take out all powers of two, you're left with 3. Just 3. The square root of 3 is less than 2 so you don't need to test *any* divisors. So you went from 3 slow divisions to zero divisions + a couple of shifts (first to remove the powers of two, then later to add them back in). A clear win.

Comment: @jairaj as for the combining: you'd have 3 powers of 2: 2, 4 and 8. These are all divisors. Now multiply each of them by 3 ("all" the other divisors, of which there happens to be only one), to get 6, 12 and 24. Then throw out 24 because it's not a proper divisor.

Answer (score 1):

This is my new C# Version. Thanks to Rndm it is almost 50 times faster than my first try.

```
public static long GetDivisors(long number)
    {
        long divisors = 0;

        long boundary = (long)Math.Sqrt(number);

        for (int i = 1; i <= boundary; i++)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)
            {
                divisors++;
                if(i != (number / i))
                {
                    if (i * i != number)
                    {
                        divisors++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return divisors;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code presented in one of the answers has a bug that is hard to see at first glance. If *sqrt(n)* is a valid divisor; but *n* is not a perfect square number,then two results are omitted.

E.g. Try `n = 15`, and see what happens; `sqrt(15) = 3`, so the last value of the while loop is 2. The next statement executed `if (i * i == n)` will be executed as `if(3 * 3 == 15)`. So 3 is not listed as a divisor, also 5 was missed.

The following will handle the general case of positive integers correctly.

```
 {
   int n;
   int i=2;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   while(i <= sqrt(n))
    {
        if(n%i==0) {
            printf("%d,",i);
            if (i != (n / i)) {
                printf("%d,",n/i);
            }
        } 

        i++;
    }
   getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  int count = 2;
     //long childsum = 0;
           long _originalvalue = sum;
     dividend = "1";
     for (int i = 2; i < sum; i++)
     {
         if (_originalvalue % i == 0)
         {
             sum = _originalvalue / i;
             //sum = childsum;
             dividend = dividend + "," + i+","+sum;
             if (sum == i)
             {
                 count++;
             }
             else
             {
                 count = count + 2;
             }
         }
     }
     return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

When the given number is odd we can even skip even numbers. 
A slight improvisation in the accepted code :)

Here it the Java code for finding factors of the given number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Factors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=scanner.nextInt();
        while(t-- > 0) {
            int n = scanner.nextInt();
            if(n % 2 == 0) {
                for(int i = 1; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
                    if(n % i == 0) {
                        System.out.println(i + ", ");
                        if(i != n/i) {
                            System.out.println(n/i + ", ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                for(int i = 1; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i=i+2) {
                    if(n % i == 0) {
                        System.out.println(i + ", ");
                        if(i != n/i) {
                            System.out.println(n/i + ", ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```